# Questions disappearing to the right

Tags: equations, align

My equations are disappearing to the right and some to the bottom in the pdf output. What is the problem? The PDF output has proportions are completely lost to the right. They seem to be too wide for the page yet I see books with longer equations than mine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a small compilable tex code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what exactly you are doing ...